# Google API map path not showing

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Following the official guide:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml

I did exactly the same thing. I jave that specific kml file on my site, and I create a page with that exact html+javascript code (copy-paste, no errors). The path for the kml file is correct too.

Of course, I inserted the right API KEY obtained by google.

Running the page, the maps shows up, in the correct start position and with the correct zoom, but I can't see any path.

How is possible?

I have only one hint: in Netbeans, I get this warning on the var map:

> The global variable "google" is not declared.

I can't figure it out.

Thank you for any help!

---

EDIT: That's my javascript as asked (it's just copy-paste from that site):

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: {lat: 41.876, lng: -87.624}
  });

  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'MYURL/cta.kml',
    map: map
  });
}
```

'MYURL' is the url of the file, that is correct (already tested). The cta.kml file is the one from that site, saved and uploaded on mine. The complete file URL is working, and the file itself has attribute 644 (publicly available) on my FTP.

Comment: Sounds like a mistake in your javascript. Can you add that to your question so we have some idea where the error might be?

Comment: Javascript added (but it's just a copy-paste from the page linked)

Comment: What is `MYURL/`? You need the full path to a publicly available KML file.  Is yours publicly available?  Is it valid? What KmlStatus is the KmlLayer returning?

Comment: 'MYURL' is the url of the file, that is correct (already tested). The cta.kml file is the one from that site, saved and uploaded on mine. The complete file URL is working, and the file itself has attribute 644 (publicly available) on my FTP.

Comment: Please don't add "SOLVED" to your question (and its title).  You can answer your own question and [accept that answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added this code in order to include Google's library?

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

Try to check for network status of this library file, in your browser devtools.

Comment: Yes, it's a complete copy-paste from the site, and my google API is correct. Altering the google API I can't see the map. Restoring the google API I see the map. It's just the path that I can't see... :-(

Comment: Pay attention to: url: 'MYURL/cta.kml'
It must to be well formed ( http:// yourdomain:port/....kml )